# I can't get the alert to fire. What am I missing?

Tags: php, jquery

I can't get the alert to fire. What am I missing?
(the code below is inside a WP plugin)

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#myTest').click(function(){alert('hi');});
</script>
<?php
    echo "<div><input type='button' value='Test' id='myTest' /></div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The script is processed before the element, so `#myTest` doesn't exist when you're assigning the handler.  Swap them around:

```
<?php
    echo "<div><input type='button' value='Test' id='myTest' /></div>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#myTest').click(function(){alert('hi');}));
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can use [*live()*](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which allows binding events to elements that don't exist yet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#myTest').live("click", function(){alert('hi');}));
</script>
<?php
    echo "<div><input type='button' value='Test' id='myTest' /></div>";
?>
```

Or make use of jQuery's [*ready()*](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler, which will fire when all elements have been parsed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
        $('#myTest').click(function(){alert('hi');}));
    });
</script>
<?php
    echo "<div><input type='button' value='Test' id='myTest' /></div>";
?>
```

Note that in the last example, I'm aliasing the jQuery namespace in the `$` argument that is passed to the function.  This allows you to use `$` for jQuery with WordPress instead of typing out `jQuery` all the time.

Comment: Why would you use `.live()` for a single element inside a `ready` handler? :)

Comment: @Nick: Damn copy & pasting... er... ahem! I mean, I have no idea what you're talking about... *whistles* ;-)

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for overdelivering :)

Comment: @Scott: no problem.  I've updated the last example to show you how you can alias the jQuery namespace, if you like :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#myTest').click(function(){alert('hi');});
});
</script>
```

By wrapping it like this, it'll wait until the element's loaded in the DOM and ready to be found by `jQuery('#myTest')`.

Answer (score 1):

The script executes before the content is loaded. When the script executes it is unable to find an element with an ID of `myTest` so it just ignores adding the event handler.

Either put the script after the event, or listen for an ( onload | document.ready ) event.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your script tags:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTest').click(function(){alert('hi');});
});
```

Comment: why not? I use both jquery and wordpress hand in hand and dont have this issue?